# Find Lockscreen Picture Location

Tags: windows, windows-10, lock-screen

I have a picture set as my lockscreen in Windows 10 but something happened and the file was deleted.

The picture is still set as my lockscreen though. Is there a way I can recover the photo?

Answer (score 1):

Found solution [Here](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/2639-lock-screen-background-image-change-windows-8-a.html)

The path is:

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\SystemData\S-1-5-21...\ReadOnly\LockScreen_(letter)
```