# Windows10 lock screen keeps changing on its own

Tags: windows-10, lock-screen

My Windows 10 lock screen picture keeps changing on its own to this picture of Nicki Minaj.

[image: low resolution picture]

Does anyone know what is going on or if there is a way to trace which process changed my lock screen?

Environment:

- Windows 10 2004
- My *Lock screen* -> *Background* is *Picture*
- Wallpaper engine

Comment: You must have downloaded the image accidently or somebody did, and the file was placed in a location, where Windows is looking for images to use for your locksceen.  [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1132023/find-lockscreen-picture-location?rq=1) is where the lockscreen image is stored.

Comment: @Ramhound I was unlikely to download this picture though. Even if it was stored in my PC, how can it be chosen and changed my original lockscreen wallpaper?
BTW, I had removed the picture which was stored in the path you offered.

Comment: Did you turn OFF Get Fun Facts in the Lock Screen Settings?  With that OFF and plain color background (my setup precisely), Lock Screen (I do use the original old bi-wing Airplane for actual Lock) never changes.

Comment: @林期間 - There could be any number of reasons the image was accidently downloaded.  The image wouldn't have been supplied by Microsoft.  The screenshot is clearly from one of her music videos, any user on the machine, could have downloaded it accidently.

Comment: @John Yeah, that option is always off.

Comment: The lockscreen images are found in the folder `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\Assets`. Take a look inside.

Comment: Kindly check if the methods provided by Rolando Vil in this similar thread was helpful to you: [Windows 10 Lock screen keeps changing](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hello/windows-10-lock-screen-keeps-changing/3a30e8fb-59ca-4abc-8879-66786d57fd0f#:~:text=Here%20are%20the%20steps%3A,to%20either%20Picture%20or%20Slideshow.)